# R.NET invoke function does not work

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I have all the necessary requirements when using the R.NET from http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

My code works just fine on R Studio, however no luck on GUI. Can anybody let me know what I am doing wrong please?

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\i386", @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1");

engine = REngine.GetInstance();

engine.Evaluate(@"source('C:/Users/achugh/Documents/Graphs/characterization.r')");
            engine.Evaluate(@"source('C:/Users/achugh/Documents/Graphs/sliderDataToComputer.r')");

var sliderfunc = engine.Evaluate("sliderdata_yprofile").AsFunction();
var directory = engine.CreateCharacterVector(new[] { "C:/Users/achugh/Documents/Graphs/data" });
var oldset = sliderfunc.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { directory }).AsDataFrame();
```

But for some reason the 'oldset' always evaluates to NULL. I already tried testing this via R-Studio

please advice?

Comment: Have you tried a minimal working example given in the doc? Does it work fine?

Comment: yes. the Minimal code works fine , even debugging it allthe way down to second last line works fine. Invoke method somehow does not function

Comment: My experience with R.NET is very limited, but I can advise trying the example at the "Calling R functions" section, which seems to have `Invoke`.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. My script returns a data frame, but for some reason the invoke function only understands that as a Numeric Matrix! Weird huh!

Comment: Glad it's resolved now. You may add this solution as an answer for future readers if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
var oldset = sliderfunc.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { directory }).AsDataFrame();
```

change the above line to :

```
var oldset = sliderfunc.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { directory }).AsNumericMatrix();
```

The reason are unknown, although the script is returning a data frame , but it fails to recognize this as data frame but recognizes this as Numeric Matrix.

Comment: I'll look at setting up a unit test to reproduce this; https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/149

Comment: I really don't think you've shown that your code returns a DataFrame and not a numeric matrix. This answer could mislead people.

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely sure your function returns a data frame and not a matrix? The following behaves exactly as expected, and as you describe. I am working from the latest code but this part of R.NET is identical to the latest 1.5.16. Please mark this post as an answer if indeed correct, just not to confuse readers as to the behavior of R data coercion.

```
var funcDef = @"function(lyrics) {return(data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8))}";
var f = engine.Evaluate(funcDef).AsFunction();
var x = f.Invoke(engine.CreateCharacter("Wo willst du hin?"));
Assert.True(x.IsDataFrame());
Assert.True(x.IsList());
var df = x.AsDataFrame();
Assert.NotNull(df);

funcDef = @"function() {return(as.matrix(data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8)))}";
f = engine.Evaluate(funcDef).AsFunction();
x = f.Invoke();
Assert.False(x.IsDataFrame());
Assert.False(x.IsList());
df = x.AsDataFrame();
Assert.Null(df);
var nm = x.AsNumericMatrix();
Assert.NotNull(nm);
```